# Headers with subscripts

Tags: header-footer

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}  %% I used Conny, but any style gives the same result
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Analytical form for ${}^3K_{rs}$ and its trace}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In the headers the subscripts are automatically changed to capital letters: how do I avoid it?

Comment: One way to avoid it: avoid using `fncychap`! ;-)

Comment: Use `\newcommand{\hidemath}{${}^3K_{rs}$} \chapter{Analytical form for \protect\hidemath{} and its trace}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion to uppercase can be reverted to lower case with `\lowercase`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Analytical form for ${}^3K_{\lowercase{rs}}$ and its trace}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Or a robust macro can be defined, that is not expanded by `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myK}{\ensuremath{^3K_{rs}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Analytical form for \myK\ and its trace}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```